# Disable editing only for UITextField?

Tags: ios, copy, uitextfield, editing, isenabled

I tried the following ways:

- properties `enabled` and "user interaction enabled";
- method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`.

But they disable all the possible actions with text field. I need to disable the editing only but allow users to copy text value. How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Implement and set the following `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return NO;
}
```

This makes the field not editable while still retaining that select/copy functionality. The `editing` property is readonly and unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you. Try

```
YourTextField.editing = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the enabled property on, and the user interaction on. Otherwise you won't be able to select the text.

set the delegate of the UITextField to the ViewController and implement :

Swift:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to tasuhka's response, make sure
`YourTextField.selectable = YES;`